# Coupon codes stored in Magento database

Tags: mysql, magento

How are coupon codes stored in the database? I have been researching online and I cant get a clear answer. I would like to write a script to import 1000 coupon codes but the Magento db schema seems to be all over the place. Can someone get me pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coupon code information is in `salesrule`.  Of course, it references product ID numbers and customer group ID numbers, so you will have to know those or access them programmatically if you want to restrict who can use the codes and what products the codes can discount.

Comment: There's no weird cross joins or anything? How does this sound? My plan is to make one coupon code the way i need it and then use that as a test format. Then write a script where the product id is a variable and you can upload coupons via csv. Do you foresee any immediate trouble with trying to attempt something like that? Just looking out for tips

Comment: I don't want to say for sure, but you should be okay. If you're not sure, create a coupon and check your logs to see what gets changed.  Also, you can check here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento_database_diagram for database information for your specific version.

Answer (score 1):

All logic needed for dealing with coupons in SalesRule module. There is model Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon which is the coupon object, and it has resource model Mage_SalesRule_Model_Mysql4_Coupon. To create new coupon you could instantiate new coupon model, fill all fields and call save() method. It will write data to table salesrule_coupon. But if you'll look at this table you'll see that coupons depend on rule id, so you need to create some sales rule first. Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule cares about rules, it also has own resource model. I think it will be helpful for you to investigate how they are works